# MySQL 8 + Regex Word Boundaries

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, where-clause, word-boundary

I want to searching for the term 'ed' at the start or end of a word, the following SQL statement only matches a exact word match.

```
SELECT * FROM ul_product
where productname REGEXP '\\bed\\b'
```

If I do the following it gets results where ed is at the start or end of a word

```
SELECT * FROM ul_product
where productname REGEXP '(\\bed)|(ed\\b)'
```

Is this how it's supposed to work?

The description of word boundary and examples online led me to believe statement 1 would produce the results of statement 2.

I can use the statements I've created as is for my 'exact' and 'partial' matching, but is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex `'\\bed\\b'` searches for `'ed'` *surrounded* by word boundaries - in other words it searches for *word* `'ed'`.

On the other end, regex: `'(\\bed)|(ed\\b)'` searches for either `'\\bed'` or `'ed\\b'` (the pipe character stands for "or" in regexes). So it matches on `'ed'` at the beginning of a word *or* at the end of a word - which seems to be what you want.

Note that the parentheses are not necessary here. You could just write this as:

```
where productname REGEXP '\\bed|ed\\b'
```

Comment: Thanks, so what I have done seems to be valid. I thought I had implemented it incorrectly in an effort to get the outcome i desired.

Comment: @DanielCook: yes, your (second) solution is OK.